# SMS verification code request failed in firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

VerificationFailed : The interaction was cancelled by the user.
this is error

[SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
I/flutter (27043): VerificationFailed : This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
W/System  (27043): A resource failed to call end.

This error shown on firebase auth for android[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duanr.png)